# Can the Dispel Magic spell be used to dispel a familiar summoned by the Find Familiar spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars

Since you cast the *find familiar* spell to get a familiar, is the familiar a magical effect? And if that is true, would you be able to target the familiar with the *dispel magic* spell and get the familiar destroyed/killed/dispelled?

Would this then be a good reason to cast *find familiar* at a higher level?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when you target a "magical effect" with Dispel Magic?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47717/what-happens-when-you-target-a-magical-effect-with-dispel-magic). Specifically, "Find familiar" has an instantaneous duration.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## No.

The familiar from *find familiar* isn't an ongoing magical effect to be dispelled. When you cast the spell (with a duration of instantaneous), the following occurs (from [the spell's text](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar)):

> You gain the service of a familiar, a spirit that takes an animal form you choose... it is a celestial, fey, or fiend (your choice) instead of a beast.

The spell doesn't create the familiar, per se. Rather, the familiar is a spirit whose service you instantaneously gain when you cast the spell. So the familiar isn't a spell effect.

In addition, the spell's duration of instantaneous indicates that there is no ongoing effect to be dispelled (from [the rules on spell duration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Instantaneous)):

> Many spells are instantaneous. The spell harms, heals, creates, or alters a creature or an object in a way that can't be dispelled, because its magic exists only for an instant.

So the familiar can't be dispelled using *dispel magic*.

For more details on dispelling magical effects, see [this related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47717/what-happens-when-you-target-a-magical-effect-with-dispel-magic).