# Can the Fortress spell be dispelled?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Does Dispel Magic work against the Mighty Fortress spell?

My GM and I couldn't decide what to do.

Comment: Related: "[What happens when you target a "magical effect" with Dispel Magic?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47717)", "[Can you dispel animated dead?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/130561)", "[Does Feeblemind produce an ongoing magical effect that can be dispelled?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/146765)", and "[Can the Dispel Magic spell be used to dispel a familiar summoned by the Find Familiar spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143212)"

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 39):

## Mighty Fortress Cannot be Dispelled

If you look at the spell description of [Mighty Fortress](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mighty-fortress) (XGtE, p. 161), you can see its Duration as a spell:

> **Duration:** Instantaneous

If you then have a look at page 203 of the Player's Handbook, you'll see the following under the descriptions of [Spell Durations](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Duration):

> **Instantaneous**
>
> Many spells are instantaneous. The spell harms, heals, creates, or alters a creature or an object in a way that **can't be dispelled**, because its magic exists only for an instant.

So, even though the structure created by Mighty Fortress crumbles after 7 days, the spell that creates it is Instantaneous in duration, and is thus immune from Dispel Magic.